# iRobot Create Serial Cable for Turtlebot I

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create, serial, roomba

I need an iRobot Create Serial Cable (one end 7-pin Mini-DIN Connector and the other end is USB) for Turtlebot I.  How can I connect my bot to my PC?

Answer (score 2):

The iRobot Create and Roomba may have a rather unusual 7-pin mini-din socket for their serial interface, but it is otherwise a fairly standard 5v serial port.

Since the original [iRobot Create cable](http://store.irobot.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2586254&cp=2600082&ab=CMS_AccessNavLP_Create_9_27&parentPage=subcategory) no longer seems to be available, if you already have a USB serial adapter and don't want to buy the new [iRobot Create 2 cable](http://store.irobot.com/communication-cable-create-2/product.jsp?productId=54235746&cp=3335976&parentPage=family), then you may want to make your own RS232 iRobot Create cable.

---

It is fairly easy to [create your own serial to roomba adapter](http://hackingroomba.com/projects/build-a-roomba-serial-tether/) with a standard RS232 cable, an 8-pin mini-din cable (the middle pin is just ignored), a MAX232 RS-232 transceiver IC, a 78L05 voltage regulator, an LED, a resistor and a few capacitors.

[image: Roomba mini-DIN-8 to RS-232 DB-9 serial interface parts (cc by-nc)]

You can connect it all together with a small piece of prototyping board, and some basic electronics tools.

[image: Roomba mini-DIN-8 to RS-232 DB-9 serial interface (cc by-nc)]

Once you have your Roomba serial to RS-232 cable, you just need to add a standard off the shelf USB to RS-232 adapter/cable to complete your connection.

Answer (score 1):

The new Create2 cable should work with old Creates and all versions of Roomba.  You can purchase one at the [iRobot web store](http://store.irobot.com/communication-cable-create-2/product.jsp?productId=54235746).  And [here](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Serial_to_USB_Cable_Creation.pdf?la=en) are instructions how to make a cable yourself using an FTDI serial to USB converter.

Please also see [www.irobot.com/create](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx) for more Roomba and Create hacks.